# How to add remote MySQL database path in application.properties?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

For now I'm using localhost

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db
```

However, when I change the path to the remote database path, it doesn't work and I get an error saying that the host (IP address) is  unauthorized to connect to the MySQL server.

I passed this path for the database

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://(IP Address):3306/my_db
```

Assuming that the database is already accessible and writable/readable if I type in the browser IP_Adress/phpmyadmin/index.php, how can I get access through Spring Boot ( I'm using the root/'' so I have the highest privileges possible).
Note that the use of the database is going to be in LAN and not in WAN.

Comment: *jdbc:mysql://(IP Address):3306/my_db* For that to work, the bind address of MySql would either have to be your LAN IP address or 0.0.0.0. Unfortunately the default is 127.0.0.1

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is not your database, it is a web application to execute queries against a database.

Comment: but the path I add is referring to what then?